# org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed when removing multiple rows from table - SWT

Tags: java, swt

I have `Table` which has `SWT.CHECK` style so I can remove checked items. I add button and `SelectionAdapter` to do the job:

```
    Button btnRemove = new Button(this, SWT.PUSH);
    btnRemove.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            TableItem[] items = table.getItems(); /* get all items */
            int i;

            for (i = 0;i < items.length;i++)
                if (items[i].getChecked()) /* look if it is selected */
                    table.remove(i);
        }
    });
```

When I remove single item, it is working fine, but when I check multiple items and then hit remove, I get `SWTException: Widget is disposed`. Here is the full stack trace:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4282)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4197)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4168)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem.getChecked(TableItem.java:423)
    at org.majid.swt.Main$1.widgetSelected(Main.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.majid.swt.Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

1. Could anyone help with this problem?
2. Is there any method like `TableItems[] getCheckedItems()` to retrieve only check items instead of checking whole items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you call `table.remove(i);` the items in the table will be different (one less) than in your array and in the next iteration the i-th item in the table is not what you expect.